# Ionic 2 - Woocommerce App - Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 while creating order using Rest Api Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, ionic2, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing a mobile application for selling different products using ionic 2 and woo-commerce rest API but when i am sending a post request for creating order on site using rest API i am getting this Error.

I am sharing my code.

**Woo-commerce Configuration**

```
let woo = new WooCommerceAPI.WooCommerceAPI({

    url: 'http://presstigersshop.dev',

    consumerKey: 'ck_2dddsdd4662e98d7c167fc8c0200177f778cf',

    consumerSecret: 'cs_1369fbdsda4448636384cb61aae5a25898e33',

    wpAPI: true,

    version: 'wc/v2'

});
```

**Order creation request using rest api**

```
var data = {

  payment_method: 'bacs',

  payment_method_title: 'Direct Bank Transfer',

  set_paid: true,

  billing: {

    first_name: 'John',

    last_name: 'Doe',

    address_1: '969 Market',

    address_2: '',

    city: 'San Francisco',

    state: 'CA',
    postcode: '94103',

    country: 'US',

    email: 'john.doe@example.com',

    phone: '(555) 555-5555'

  },

  shipping: {

    first_name: 'John',

    last_name: 'Doe',

    address_1: '969 Market',

    address_2: '',

    city: 'San Francisco',

    state: 'CA',

    postcode: '94103',

    country: 'US'

  },

  line_items: [

    {

      product_id: 93,

      quantity: 2

    },

    {

      product_id: 22,

      variation_id: 23,

      quantity: 1

    }

  ],

  shipping_lines: [

    {

      method_id: 'flat_rate',

      method_title: 'Flat Rate',

      total: 10

    }

  ]

};


woo.post('orders', data, function(err, data, res) {

  console.log(res);

});
```

**htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Error That i am Facing:

[image: Error That i am Facing]

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en try to install this in your chrome and enable it and then check

Comment: Still getting the same problem #Mohan Gopi

Comment: Issue Resolved after testing it on device thanks #Mohan Gopi

Comment: @Adnan After you deploy to a device the error has stopped? How did you do to test in development? I have the same problem

Comment: @RafaelAcioly I attached device with my system using data cable and simply run command "ionic run android" it automatically deploy the application on my device, after that using chrome debugging i test it...and its working :)